# Confusion regarding definition of angle

Tags: geometry, angle

My teacher defined an angle as the measure of the size of rotation of a ray around the vertex. But recently I stumbled across the Wikipedia article on angles, which defines an angle as the figure formed by two rays with a common endpoint, the vertex. So which definition is correct? Are both of them correct, perhaps?

Also, how exactly should I visualize this "figure"? The Wikipedia article provides the following picture:

[image]

So is that green sector the angle? Or is it both of the rays combined? I'm really confused and would appreciate any help

Comment: I think it's just a case of two people defining a term in similar ways - notice that they are telling essentially the same thing.

Comment: So it's a thing, or the size/measure of that thing. The word "angle" is used for both the figure and the number that is that figure's size measurement.

Comment: My favourite definition of angle is the intersection of two half-planes.

Comment: (+1) for a good question, but voting to close as a duplicate.